# Web scraping with R and RSelenium -- difficulty with drop down menu and select

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I'm trying to access files from this website: https://public.education.mn.gov/MDEAnalytics/DataTopic.jsp?TOPICID=11 I want the level to correspond to county, and I want to do it for each year. For the sake of this example, assume I only want to do it for 2022. I got RSelenium up and running, but everything I've tried to find the select menu elements with RSelenium hasn't worked.

For instance:

```
remDr <- remote_driver$client
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://public.education.mn.gov/MDEAnalytics/DataTopic.jsp?TOPICID=11")
data_table <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "cmbCOLuMN")
```

returns an error: "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters".

I've tried to change the using and values parameters in `findElement()`, and still no such luck. I would be grateful for any insight into how to select the level to be County and the year to be 2022.

**Update**: I was able to make more progress with this code based on a previous stackoverflow response that talks about iframes, but am still getting stuck at the end:

```
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://public.education.mn.gov/MDEAnalytics/DataTopic.jsp?TOPICID=11") 
frames <- remDr$findElements('css', "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
selectElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "cmbCOLUMN1")
selectOpt <- selectElem$selectTag()
```

I'm not able to use selectOpt feature to choose the value I want, which would be something like `SelectOpt$text$County`

Comment: I checked the site, the id is `cmbCOLUMN1` not `cmbCOLuMN1.select`

Comment: Thank you, TamTam. I have updated the code and formatting based on your suggestions. I am still receiving an error after the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a second iframe. I ran your code through this:

```
frames <- remDr$findElements('css', "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
```

Then  clicked the "list files" button using its html id.

```
# click on a button ------------------------------------
remDr$findElement(using = "id",value = "button1")$clickElement()
```

Clicking on that button shows all the available files in a second iframe, so I found the second iframe with its html id (`#report`) and switched to it.

```
# switch to iframe 2 ------------------------------------
report_frame <- remDr$findElement(using = "id",value = "report")
remDr$switchToFrame(report_frame)
```

Then I pulled the page's html and scaned it for tables

```
# Pull page html
page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()

# extract tables

tables <- page_html %>% html_table()

files_table <- tables[[2]]
```

I'm assuming this is what you wanted? A data frame with a list of all the available files:

```
# A tibble: 1,458 × 6
   X1       X2       X3     X4                                     X5     X6   
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>                                  <chr>  <chr>
 1 ""       ""       ""     ""                                     ""     ""   
 2 "Level"  "Name"   "Year" "Document"                             "Data… "Hel…
 3 "County" "Aitkin" "2022" "2022 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
 4 "County" "Aitkin" "2019" "2019 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
 5 "County" "Aitkin" "2016" "2016 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
 6 "County" "Aitkin" "2013" "2013 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
 7 "County" "Anoka"  "2022" "2022 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
 8 "County" "Anoka"  "2019" "2019 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
 9 "County" "Anoka"  "2016" "2016 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
10 "County" "Anoka"  "2013" "2013 Minnesota Student Survey County" "pdf"  ""   
# … with 1,448 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I'm going to count this as answered, because this was a really helpful response to a conceptual hurdle I was struggling with. Thank you!